# This code Work with me Except the main Button it did not go to MainMenu class?

Tags: android, button, program-entry-point

any one can help

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FlashLightActivity extends Activity {


Button main;

//flag to detect flash is on or off
private boolean isLighOn = false;



private Camera camera;


private Button button;

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
    }
}




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

The problem here

```
    main=(Button)this.findViewById(R.id.main);
    main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(FlashLightActivity.this, "main",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent myinIntent=new Intent(v.getContext(),MainMenu.class); 
            startActivity(myinIntent);
            //this.finish();


        }



    });
```

This Work will

```
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFlashlight);


    Context context = this;
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    // if device support camera?
    if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
        return;
    }

    camera = Camera.open();
    final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

flash work here

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (isLighOn) {

                Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.stopPreview();
                isLighOn = false;

            } else {

                Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();
                isLighOn = true;

            }

        }
    });





    }

}
```

not all activities have the behavior that they are destroyed when BACK is pressed. When the user starts playing music in the Music application and then presses BACK, the application overrides the normal back behavior, preventing the player activity from being destroyed, and continues playing music, even though its activity is no longer visible

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing :-

```
Intent myinIntent=new Intent(v.getContext(),MainMenu.class);
```

with

```
Intent myinIntent=new Intent(this,MainMenu.class);
```